# DataTemplateSelector disappearing data on save mystery

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, datatemplate

I'm not even sure what to call it so let me explain the scenario and hopefully a light bulb goes off for somebody else. I can't do a full code share to reproduce because it just isn't an option, anyhow I digress.

So, here's the basics.

Multiple DataTemplate's set via;

```
    public DataTemplate ABCTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate) GetValue(ABCTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ABCTemplateTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
```

Which are swapped out via;

```
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var something = (thestuff)item;

        switch (something.Id)
        {
            case (int)thestuff.Type.ABC: { return ABCTemplate; }
            case (int)thestuff.Type.DEF: { return DEFTemplate; }
            case (int)thestuff.Type.GHI: { return GHITemplate; }
            case (int)thestuff.Type.JKL: { return JKLTemplate; }
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
```

etc, etc, etc. Each DataTemplate is a DataGrid (no I did not make this and I can't rewrite it).

Here's the weird mystery part that has me stumped that I'll explain best I can.

On initial load of the screen everything is fine, the data loads fine, everything is peachy. HOWEVER upon Save (even without any changes) once the busy indicator disposes then ONLY the Column Headers of the DataGrids will remain visible **UNTIL** you resize the screen even the slightest bit. Which I assume causes SizeChanged to UpdateLayout()?

My question is, has anyone seen this behavior before? Why the hell would the DataGrid of each template render the Column Headers, but then NOT render the rows until just a SizeChanged event, and most importantly, how can I fix this P.O.S.?

I tried the first stuff I could think of like just hard setting some sizes since I took a shot in the dark on the fact that changing the window size even the slightest bit causes the data to return to view but in reality, I'm stumped and doing that just made it less predictably reproducible.

I'll happily buy beer for anyone that can save my sanity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This actually does ring a bell. I had to fight a similar `DataGrid` rendering issue. Here is my story:

The content disappeared or was completely white when we added columns, after a while I found out it happened when the combined width of all columns exceeded a certain number. I don't think it was `Int32.MaxValue`, it was probably a smaller number, maybe it was a power of two, but that is not important or required. (see my explanation further down)

So your save operation's busy indicator might effect the visualState in any way, some kind of focus border or stuff might be rendered and just hits this magical limit, an overflow will happen.

Now imagine some code that for example calculates the width of a contentPanel or Presenter (or anything related to showing your content) sums up all the parts, and an overflow happens, what will be the result? yeah, exactly, the width will be far in the negative. So it actually might be rendered by the engine, either off screen or just outside of the element's actual display area.

You can actually reproduce this and witness it with a `TextBox` in a try-out project: Have a TextBox and fill it with random characters via Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V, and onTextChanged -> Debug.WriteLine(textbox.Text.GetRenderedWidth()).
(GetRenderedWidth is an extension method I wrote, can give you the code if you want. But it is not super accurate.)
As soon as the rendered width reaches ca. 39,235 you can see a change in the rendering of the Ctrl+A text highlighter: The content is gone! But actually it is just rendered into negative direction (you can turn on [EnableRedrawRegions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838252(v=vs.95).aspx) to see it rendered in the wrong direction). and everything is back to normal when you remove the last character again.

So my advise is: turn on EnableRedrawRegions, see if you can see a change of the redrawn regions when your rendering issue occurrs. If you can spot a region is drawn just left of you DataGrid, chances are that that is actually your grid content.

**[Edit 1]**
If it turns out that the visualState change of the grid is somehow causing this bug, your fix might be as simple as onBusyIndicatorDone -> `VisualStateManager.GoToState(grid,"normal",false);`

**[Edit 2]**
You can trigger a redraw with [InvalidateArrange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange(v=vs.95).aspx) or [InvalidateMeasure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatemeasure(v=vs.95).aspx): `grid.InvalidateArrange()` or `grid.InvalidateMeasure()`

Comment: Ok cool, I'm just now swinging back this morning so I'll have to tinker with the suggestions thanks man. Oh and PS I'll be in .ch in August but not sure if I'll make it to .de this trip. Wenn Sie möchten, um ein Bier zu greifen. :)

Comment: Would be cool if we could have the beers. Tinker with it, let me know of any new facts.

Comment: Man this thing is still the bane of my existence after coming back to it today. The way they have views super nested and intertwined hasn't produced me anything specific to look at. The Invalidate methods for a layout update cause issues elsewhere, the VSM state cancellation doesn't seem to propagate right. It's very instance specific but I'm still stumped. Am going to swing back to this tomorrow and either way you know I'm going to count this correct lol. Just leaving it open a bit longer to see if it doesn't attract other suggestions to this over engineered garbage I'm working with lol.

Comment: I even tried just replacing the entire datagrid with a bare bones basic ItemsControl with no luck so that cancels out the VSM possibility. It would be nice if I could just get it to feed me some sort of exception or any info on where to look. At this rate I'm just going to have to talk them into letting me re-write a lot of it since it's really over engineered as it is.

Comment: You don't need to mark it as accepted, you already upvoted ;) I'm out of ideas here. Will drop you a line when anything potentially useful crosses my mind.

Comment: Ya it's really odd. I had to swing off of it for a bit to get some other things done but I suspect there's something weird going on with how they have so many super nested virtualization instances into what's overall a kind of odd front end approach I'd never suggest. Perhaps some sort of sync issue when RIA runs onsave and an error I'm not getting reported back or something to re-populate the rows since the header always remains fine and visible. It really is an odd one. Oh well, I still owe you a beer either way whenever you're ready for it lol.